# JcomboBox with Sqlite Database

Tags: java, mysql, sqlite, jdbc, jcombobox

[image: I have never ever seen such an error..]

I was just trying to call data from the database when I press a button. Here's my code

```
JButton btnRefresh = new JButton("Refresh");
    btnRefresh.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            Connection conni = null;
            ResultSet rs=null;
            PreparedStatement pst=null;
            try{
                Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
                conni  = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite://C://Users//Asus//Dropbox//TireShop.sqlite");
                String sql="select * from Namet";


                pst=conni.prepareStatement(sql);
                rs=pst.executeQuery();
                while(rs.next()){
                    String name = rs.getString("Namet");
                    comboBox.addItem(name);

                }

            }catch(Exception i){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);

            }
```

Then this thing keeps coming when I press refresh.

Comment: You are showing `ActionEvent e`in the dialog but your exception is named `i`. Please output `i` and you will understand what's wrong in your JDBC code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To demonstrate Florent's comment, change

```
        }catch(Exception i){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);

        }
```

to

```
        }catch(Exception i){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, i);

        }
```

so you can see the exception.